# OAuth2 server: invalid or missing grant_type parameter

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a NodeJS-based OAuth2 server (using `oauth2-server` module) started in my LAN. I want to test it with Postman REST Client but I'm getting this error response:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Invalid or missing grant_type parameter"
}
```

This is my request configuration:

[image: Request]

I have tried to send the parameters by URL but I get the error: `Method must be POST with application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using postman you send the value as a query parameter but 'oauth2-server' checks the value as a body parameter using 'req.body'.so try to send the value as a body parameter or change the req.body to req.query inside node_modules/oauth2-server/lib/grant.js

Comment: Thanks for answering. Weeks ago I changed `oauth2-server` by `'oauth2orize` module. It is working properly.